# How to fade out the edges of a Java2D Area object?

Tags: java, gradient, shadow, java-2d, area

I have a method that creates shadows based on where things are on the screen and the final product of that method is an Area, which I then draw onto the screen and it contains all shadows on screen in the same Area. This is because the drawn shadows are a low opacity so if it is not all one thing they will overlap and the opacity will make it look weird.

The issue that I want the shadows to look like they fade out, but I have absolutely no idea how, or if that would even be possible. Is there a way to soften the edges of the Area or make them gradient fade out? I tried to do graphics2D.setPaint(new GradientPaint[a gradient effect]) but it did nothing.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: [image: Here] Here is a screenshot of the program making a shadow around a 'building' rectangle. The green rectangle is to show the effect of the shadow. The end result I want is instead of the shadow abruptly ending, it should fade out.

Comment: maybe you show us an example area and the problem you have with it (a picture says more than 1000 words)

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: uhm, sorry, there went something wrong when you tried to add an image :/ it's not visible!

Comment: Oops, added for real!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have problems setting up the proper colors for the gradient:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);            
    g.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 20);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Polygon p = new Polygon(new int[]{10,20,50,50,40,10}, new int[]{10,10,40,50,50,20}, 6);
    Area a = new Area(p);

    Color b = new Color(0xFF000000, true); //using colors with transparency!!!
    Color w = new Color(0x00FFFFFF, true); //using colors with transparency!!!

    //try to use proper values for the x/y values - both, start and end
    GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(0, 0, b, 40, 40, w);                     
    g2d.setPaint(gradient);
    g2d.fill(a); // fill your area!
}
```

result is a gradient with alpha (Transparency) ...

[image: red - no gradient][image]

Area drawn in red <==> Area drawn with Gradient

don't forget to set the alpha value `0xAARRGGBB` to `FF` for 100% opaque (`0xFF000000` is black 100%opaque) to 0 (`0x00FFFFFF` white, 100% transparent)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately this method won't work for me, because the area contains multiple shadows (imaging the image I posted but with several other 'buildings' on screen, each with shadows, where every one of those shadows is in a single Area. This means that I cant get the endpoints of the gradient line. This is why I was curious more about how to dull/fade the edges of the Area.

Comment: @Miles can you tell me more about your areas?

Comment: So every time a new building is added, a method executes that generates shadows, which more technically looks at the corners of each building based on the location of a light source and generates a polygon accordingly. Then it adds each of those polygons to an Area (just the Java2D area, like Area a = new Area(); a.add(polygon)). This is because the shadows are partially transparent and if I did not add them to an area, which when drawn essentially ignores overlap, they would appear darker at the overlaps of the shadows.